# Emacs command M-? undefined

Tags: emacs

I'm running emacs 24.5.1 on an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine on a Windows 7 machine (all 64 bit). I'm trying to use my tags file to navigate a source tree. `M-.` and `M-*` work great but when I try the `M-?` command, it says it is undefined. I do not see this on other Emacs I am using; for example, on Windows 7, my Emacs 25.3.1 works fine. Why is that particular command broken? My `init.el` file has nothing in it but a line to ignore case on tab completion.

Comment: Is it the key binding or the function that it is bound to that's undefined? What does `C-h c M-?` say?

Comment: It seems like xref was added in 25.1.  I'd recommend building your own Emacs or using a ppa.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. C-h c M-? says it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

@jpkotta had the right idea. Building emacs 25.3.1 fixed this problem. I'm not sure why this ancient command disappeared in emacs 24.